# Flash Packager for iPhone: Possible to use Core-Data or other database?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, flash

I'm wondering if the flash packager for iPhone allows you to somehow save data in some kind of database maybe using Core Data or any other form?

If it just allows you to export some kind of actionscript based game but doesn't allow for saving data that'd be kinda weak I'd assume so they must have a way (?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2), it works fine. It corresponds to NSKeyedArchiver for iPhone.